# Call Abstract toString() When its Been Overwritten by Child Class

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, tostring

I have an **abstract Course class** with subclasses of Course. Course has it's own toString method and subclasses have an overwritten toString() method.

I have created a **new Class Student** that uses an array of **Course[]** with different subclasses instances ie Course[0] list = new SubClassName() etc.

When I use toString() on list[0] it calls the subclass toString.

**How can I have access to the parent toString() method when it's been overwritten?**

Thanks

Comment: Understand that toString is used mainly for debugging and not for production.  It sounds like you're not doing this.

Comment: Also, please provide a [mcve] in future - it's a lot easier to read actual code than a *description* of code.

Comment: Basically, you can't do that.  Once a method is overridden, it's overridden.

Comment: * "overridden". "Overwritten" has an entirely different meaning.

Comment: Thanks Louis Wasserman that is what I wanted to know.